# xrdp to Ubuntu loads different session

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp

When I use my PC A to log into remote desktop of the server, which runs Ubuntu, run some program (say MATLAB), close the connection and re-log into the server, the MATLAB still runs.

However, if I use my PC B to re-log into the server, it seems a new session and no MATLAB window can be seen. But `top` shows the MATLAB is running.

How can I log into the same session I started using PC A?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, there are 2 ways to do this:

1. [[Source]](http://ubuntuwiki.net/index.php/Xrdp,_installing) Editing xrdp.ini to add a custom `local login`

   - Make sure you have xrdp and vino installed

     ```
     sudo apt-get install xrdp vino
     ```
   - Edit `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini`

     ```
     sudo gedit /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
     ```
   - copy `xrdp1` block and change its number to something else which is not already there in the ini file. Basically the number here decides the dropdown order. Add this

     ```
     [xrdp1] 
     name=MyLocalLogin 
     lib=libvnc.so 
     username= password=ask
     ip=127.0.0.1 
     port=5900
     ```
   - Now just try rdp'ing and choose your custom session `MyLocalLogin`
2. [[Source]](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=4168) I haven't tried this yet. It looks somewhat painful as it involves modifying and re-compiling the xrdp source.

   - Install basic stuff needed.

     ```
     sudo apt-get install autoconf libtool libpam0g-dev libx11-dev libxfixes-dev libssl-dev
     sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
     echo  ”gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback” > ~/.xsession   
     sudo apt-get install x11vnc
     ```
   - Download the xrdp source from [here](https://github.com/FreeRDP/xrdp). Now extract it anywhere, lets call it root. Go to root/xrdp-master and :

     ```
     sudo ./bootstrap
     sudo ./configure
     sudo make
     sudo make install
     ```
   - Now we need to configure our system in order to have xrdp using X11Vnc package and have the xrdp service started automatically when the Ubuntu computer is restarted.

     ```
     sudo apt-get install xrdp 
     sudo apt-get remove xrdp
     sudo mv startwm.sh startwm.sh.backup 
     sudo ln -s /etc/X11/Xsession /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh 
     sudo mkdir /usr/share/doc/xrdp 
     sudo cp /etc/xrdp/rsakeys.ini /usr/share/doc/xrdp/rsakeys.ini
     ```
   - Now we need to update the `/etc/init.d/xrdp`. Simply copy the content of the modified xrdp script file into your /etc/init.d/xrdp

     ```
     <-------   Begin of the Script -------->

     #!/bin/sh -e
     #
     # start/stop xrdp and sesman daemons
     #
     ### BEGIN INIT INFO
     # Provides:          xrdp
     # Required-Start:    $network $remote_fs
     # Required-Stop:     $network $remote_fs
     # Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
     # Default-Stop:      0 1 6
     # Short-Description: Start xrdp and sesman daemons
     # Description:       XRDP uses the Remote Desktop Protocol to present a
     #                    graphical login to a remote client allowing connection
     #                    to a VNC server or another RDP server.
     ### END INIT INFO

     PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
     DAEMON=/usr/local/sbin/xrdp
     PIDDIR=/var/run
     SESMAN_START=yes
     USERID=xrdp
     RSAKEYS=/etc/xrdp/rsakeys.ini
     NAME=xrdp
     DESC="Remote Desktop Protocol server"

     test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

     . /lib/lsb/init-functions

     check_root()  {
         if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
             log_failure_msg "You must be root to start, stop or restart $NAME."
             exit 4
         fi
     }

     if [ -r /etc/default/$NAME ]; then
        . /etc/default/$NAME
     fi

     # Tasks that can only be run as root
     if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]; then
         # Check for pid dir
         if [ ! -d $PIDDIR ] ; then
             mkdir $PIDDIR
         fi
         chown $USERID:$USERID $PIDDIR

         # Check for rsa key 
         if [ ! -f $RSAKEYS ] || cmp $RSAKEYS /usr/share/doc/xrdp/rsakeys.ini > /dev/null; then
             log_action_begin_msg "Generating xrdp RSA keys..."
             (umask 077 ; xrdp-keygen xrdp $RSAKEYS)
             chown $USERID:$USERID $RSAKEYS
             if [ ! -f $RSAKEYS ] ; then
                 log_action_end_msg 1 "could not create $RSAKEYS"
                 exit 1
             fi
             log_action_end_msg 0 "done"
         fi
     fi

     case "$1" in
       start)
             check_root
             exitval=0
             log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC " 
             if pidofproc -p $PIDDIR/$NAME.pid $DAEMON > /dev/null; then
                 log_progress_msg "$NAME apparently already running"
                 log_end_msg 0
                 exit 0
             fi
             log_progress_msg $NAME
             start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo  --pidfile $PIDDIR/$NAME.pid \
             --chuid $USERID:$USERID --exec $DAEMON
             exitval=$?
         if [ "$SESMAN_START" = "yes" ] ; then
                 log_progress_msg "sesman"
                 start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDDIR/xrdp-sesman.pid \
                --exec /usr/local/sbin/xrdp-sesman
                 value=$?
                 [ $value -gt 0 ] && exitval=$value
             fi
             # Make pidfile readables for all users (for status to work)
             [ -e $PIDDIR/xrdp-sesman.pid ] && chmod 0644 $PIDDIR/xrdp-sesman.pid
             [ -e $PIDDIR/$NAME.pid ] && chmod 0644 $PIDDIR/$NAME.pid
             # Note: Unfortunately, xrdp currently takes too long to create
             # the pidffile unless properly patched
             log_end_msg $exitval
         ;;
       stop)
             check_root
         [ -n "$XRDP_UPGRADE" -a "$RESTART_ON_UPGRADE" = "no" ] && {
             echo "Upgrade in progress, no restart of xrdp."
             exit 0
         }
             exitval=0
             log_daemon_msg "Stopping RDP Session manager " 
             log_progress_msg "sesman"
             if pidofproc -p  $PIDDIR/xrdp-sesman.pid /usr/local/sbin/xrdp-sesman  > /dev/null; then
                 start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDDIR/xrdp-sesman.pid \
                     --chuid $USERID:$USERID --exec /usr/local/sbin/xrdp-sesman
                 exitval=$?
             else
                 log_progress_msg "apparently not running"
             fi
             log_progress_msg $NAME
             if pidofproc -p  $PIDDIR/$NAME.pid $DAEMON  > /dev/null; then
                 start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDDIR/$NAME.pid \
             --exec $DAEMON
                 value=$?
                 [ $value -gt 0 ] && exitval=$value
             else
                 log_progress_msg "apparently not running"
             fi
             log_end_msg $exitval
         ;;
       restart|force-reload)
             check_root
         $0 stop
             # Wait for things to settle down
             sleep 1
         $0 start
         ;;
       reload)
             log_warning_msg "Reloading $NAME daemon: not implemented, as the daemon"
             log_warning_msg "cannot re-read the config file (use restart)."
             ;;
       status)
             exitval=0
             log_daemon_msg "Checking status of $DESC" "$NAME"
             if pidofproc -p  $PIDDIR/$NAME.pid $DAEMON  > /dev/null; then
                 log_progress_msg "running"
                 log_end_msg 0
             else
                 log_progress_msg "apparently not running"
                 log_end_msg 1 || true
                 exitval=1
             fi
         if [ "$SESMAN_START" = "yes" ] ; then
                 log_daemon_msg "Checking status of RDP Session Manager" "sesman"
                 if pidofproc -p  $PIDDIR/xrdp-sesman.pid /usr/local/sbin/xrdp-sesman  > /dev/null; then
                     log_progress_msg "running"
                     log_end_msg 0
                 else
                     log_progress_msg "apparently not running"
                     log_end_msg 1 || true
                     exitval=1
                 fi
             fi
             exit $exitval
             ;;
       *)
         N=/etc/init.d/$NAME
         echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}" >&2
         exit 1
         ;;
     esac

     exit 0
     ```